# Does this video show Israeli police brutalizing anti-Zionist Jews?

Tags: israel, antisemitism

[Caution: Attached video portrays moderate violence by police.]

According to [this tweet by the Quds News Network](https://twitter.com/QudsNen/status/1719745919011213714)

> Israeli police on Wednesday raided the anti-Zionist Jewish neighborhood in occupied #Jerusalem to take down Palestinian flags and brutally attacked anti-Zionist Jews, knocking them down on the road, hitting, and punching them in the face.

This video seems to show a police officer throwing an orthodox Jew to the ground, and slapping another Orthodox Jew that he pushes into a building. Was this assault done because the Orthodox Jews were anti-Zionist? Is there any evidence that Palestinian flags were removed (I don't see any flags in the video)?

Comment: This video shows Palestinian flags being confiscated by the police:
https://twitter.com/i/status/1713382802476134876

Comment: Not the same video but a similar tweet apparently debunked by Newsweek: https://www.newsweek.com/fact-check-does-video-show-israelis-arrested-supporting-palestinians-1837824

Comment: @BrianZ there are a few like that of _other_ videos which have been debunked. There is also a protest attended to by the Ultra orthodox pertaining to lockdowns that I found which was also wrongly attributed to Palestine. However, the video in question doesn't show a protest even happening. It's just police brutalizing people. For this reason I'm more inclined to believe this instance.

Comment: The watermark on the video comes from:
https://twitter.com/BETZEDEC/status/1719701912398729542
An account dedicated to denounce police brutality according to its bio.
The description of the video when automatically translated to English says:
"Today, during a police raid to take down Palestinian flags in the anti-Zionist Jewish neighborhood, Mea Shearim in Jerusalem,
The Israeli policemen were recorded attacking the residents and knocking them down on the road, hitting and punching them in the face."
If the video can be geolocated to Mea Shearim, it is a known anti-zionist neighborhood.

Comment: Is the question "Does this video show Israeli police attacking Jews?" Is the question "Are these Jews publicly anti-Zionist?" Is the question "Did the police take down Palestinian flags?" If the question is "Were police motivated to attack these Jews because they are anti-Zionist?" it is off-topic here.

Comment: See also: https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4992/what-makes-a-good-question-about-the-2023-israel-hamas-war

Comment: @Oddthinking That's simply not true. Respectfully. I've found multiple cases where the police attacked Orthodox Jews for (a) assembling to resist IDF drafts, (b) assembling to resist lockdown measures. If there is an anti-Zionist neighborhood, you can be skeptical of the claim that they were attacked _because_ they were anti-Zionist if for example they're organizing for one of the causes above. However, if the police are principally engaged in removing Palestinian flags, it stands to reason that's why they were attacked. Does any of this sound unreasonable to you?

Comment: @Oddthinking Would you for example, grant that it's possible and very material whether or not anti-Zionist Jews were attacked for protesting against coronavirus measures? I don't want to deny Israel of that defense. It also seems it's reasonable to interpret "brutally attacked anti-Zionist Jews" as "brutally attacked Jews for being anti-Zionist". Though perhaps that's not explicitly the claim, it's certainly the tone I got.

Comment: "That's simply not true." Do you mean my statement that a question about the motivation of the police is off-topic here is wrong? I can give you references to meta-questions on the topic if that is the case. As for your hypothetical: It is possible that someone would be attacked by another because of coronavirus protests. It may be material. It would also be off-topic here to ask what the motivations were.

Comment: In the meantime: The question is currently too broad, and the answer you like doesn't cover all of it. Let's whittle it down to match the answer.

Comment: @Oddthinking yes, I would be interested in seeing the meta topics covering this point you raise about motivations. I don't understand why they would be off-topic. It's simply context. The bar in a criminal court is "reasonable doubt". I would have reasonable doubt as to these Jews being victims of Zionist violence for their anti-Zionism if they were at a coronavirus protest, and I wouldn't have reasonable doubt if the cop was removing their Palestinian flags (which wasn't captured in the video).

Comment: Here is the [FAQ](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/887/23). Here is [the original discussion](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/621/politics-beliefs-and-motivations-questions-should-not-be-allowed-here). Here is [some more discussion](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4186/23).

Comment: @EvanCarroll The presence and removal of the flags can be checked. The Zionism of the participants can not - sure, they are attacking orthodox-looking jews in a known anti-Zionist neighborhood, but as far as I can tell, there are no political statements made, no flags or placards. According to a google search - police are attacked regularly in that neighbourhood, how do we know this is a political issue and not just an overreaction to someone keying a police car?

Comment: All valid, bar for truth is too high there imho. Relatively normal problem around here, different people require more information. I need only know they removed Palestinian flags, and that there was no reason to believe otherwise (such as lockdown protest, or anti-IDF draft demonstration) to satisfy my bar for it being politically motivated.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: Does that mean we can reach a compromise, and change the question to "Did these police take down Palestinian flags before this incident?"

Comment: @Oddthinking yes, certainly I'm down for compromising. The only reason why I feel that's undesirable is because if there is no Palestinian flags, and these are just Orthodox Jews in a anti-zionist neighborhood doing nothing otherwise that's political, I think the substance of the tweet is still overwhelmingly true (less the bit about the flags).

Comment: @Evan: I am looking at the tweet for the bit you doubt. Police raided a neighborhood? Doesn't seem in doubt. The neigborhood is anti-Zionist, Jewish and in occupied Jerusalem? Bit nebulous but probably answerable. 
Israeli police on Wednesday raided the anti-Zionist Jewish neighborhood in occupied #Jerusalem to take down Palestinian flags and brutally attacked anti-Zionist Jews, knocking them down on the road, hitting, and punching them in the face. Took down Palestinian flags? Testable, but not interesting? [cont'd]

Comment: Brutally attacked people? Seems clear to me, but police brutality videos are notoriously interpreted differently by different political groups.  The attacked people were Orthodox Jews? Their clothes don't *prove* anything, but I don't think this is in doubt. The attacked people were openly Anti-Zionist? Tricky to answer, but maybe we can find interviews with the victims.

Comment: It is common with police brutality videos for people to ask "But what did they do before the video started which may have justified the police acting that way?" provoking political arguments. I don't believe you are going in that angle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The incident happened here:
[image]
You can check the location on Google Maps Street View:
https://maps.app.goo.gl/KK2dqUg7cWi3GRxE8

On the Street View picture, you can see Palestine flags on the walls.
Mea Shearim is a known anti-zionist neighborhood:
https://www.timesofisrael.com/anti-zionists-in-ultra-orthodox-neighborhood-attack-firemen-on-independence-day/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MwaP_YVJtjc

In April, the police led workers to this neighborhood to remove a Palestinian flag from a wall:
https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/israel-news/2185531/sunday-fun-police-officers-raid-mea-shearim-remove-palestinian-flags.html

It is reasonable to assume they occasionally raid the neighborhood to remove signs alluding to Palestine, as they have done recently:
https://www.timesofisrael.com/liveblog_entry/police-remove-hateful-graffiti-in-jerusalems-mea-shearim-neighborhood/

The Neturei Karta group is present in Mea Shearim and has occasionally clashed with the police as the article above mentions for anti-zionist protests such as burning the Israeli flag.
Why the gentlemen was assaulted is impossible to tell, but the description of the video is accurate.